# Mobile Version Add to Cart redirect Customisation

Tags: html, css, shopify

Once customer using mobile to add to cart how can it straight away redirect it to checkout page? I am using shopify which code should i change?

```
<a 
    {% if func == "" %} href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="quiqview('{{ product.handle | handleize }}')"
    {% else %} href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{{ func }}; return false;"
    {% endif %}
    class="btn btn--wd buy-link">
        <span class="icon icon-ecommerce"></span>
        <span class="product-preview__info__link__text">Add to cart</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is the code i think but i don't know how to change it            <a {% if func == "" %}href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="quiqview('{{ product.handle | handleize }}')"{% else %}href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{{ func }}; return false;"{% endif %} class="btn btn--wd buy-link"><span class="icon icon-ecommerce"></span><span class="product-preview__info__link__text">Add to cart</span></a>